# Apache Solr Search for Distance Calculation

Tags: python, solr, lucene, face-recognition

Hi I am using Apache solr v8

I need to calculate distance between n-dim vector in query search,
how could i do that.

Because I need to calculate distance between face encoding vectors in python's Face_recognition module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
There is a `dist` function in Solr, see answer provided by the original poster.

Approximate Near Neighbor (ANN) vector search is not yet natively supported in Solr. There is an ongoing effort to integrate it in both Solr and Lucene. You can find a detailed analysis and track progress on this Solr Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-14397

There is also a section "Note on Prior Approaches" on the ticket that summarizes the solutions/workarounds so far for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
The distance formula should apply in sort field

```
sort : dist(2, db_vector_header, user_vector) asc
```

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question then, and there is a `dist` function that I was unaware of. By the way, you can use the same function on the query in this form: q=`{!func}dist(2, db_vector_header, user_vector)`